# Suppose $(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \sim \text{Dirichlet}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$. What is the joint distribution of $(X_1 + X_2, X_3 + X_4, X_5, \cdots, X_n)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to solve this using the change of variables formula. Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $$T(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = (x_1 + x_2, x_3 + x_4, x_5, \cdots, x_n, x_2, x_4).$$
Then $T$ is invertible with inverse:
$$T^{-1}(y_1, \cdots, y_n) = (y_1 - y_{n-1}, y_{n-1}, y_2 - y_n, y_n, y_3, \cdots, y_{n-2}).$$
Then if $f$ is the density of $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$, the density of $(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n) = T(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is $f \circ T^{-1}$ which is proportional to:
$$(y_1 - y_{n-1})^{a_1 - 1}(y_{n-1})^{a_2 - 1}(y_2 - y_n)^{a_3 - 1}(y_n)^{a_4 - 1}(y_3)^{a_5 - 1} \cdots (y_{n-2})^{a_n - 1}.$$
Now I want to integrate out $y_{n-1}$ and $y_n$, but I end up with integrals which look like $\int_0^{y_1} (y_1 - y_{n-1})^{a_1 - 1}(y_{n-1})^{a_2 - 1}\ dy_{n-1}$, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Is there a simpler way to approach this problem?

Comment: I had always assumed $(X_1 + X_2, X_3 + X_4, X_5, \ldots, X_n)$ would be  $\sim \text{Dirichlet}(a_1+a_2,a_3+a_4,a_5, \ldots, a_n)$ which ought to tell you what your integral should be

Comment: @Henry How can I prove this? Looks like this is called the aggregation property. Thank you, I will learn more about this.

Comment: By the change of variables theorem for integration, the density of $TX$ is $(f \circ T^{-1})1/\det(T)$